# Building the wsgi script for Flask with zc.buildout

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, buildout

I'm building an app with Rest services powered with Flask. And I want to have it deployed with Apache / mod_wsgi as described here : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

But I'm stuck for building the myapp.wsgi file that's required from Apache. More specifically, I cannot achieve tweaking the sys.path such all eggs from buildout required for my app can be included. The recipes I found require PasteScript and PasteDeploy that I don't want in my software stack.

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    # How to compute the paths to add since I need 'foo' and 'bar' eggs
    # that are created by buildout ?
    ]
from foo import app as application
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use PasteDeploy and collective.recipe.modwsgi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.modwsgi/

Simple .ini file:

```
[app:main]
paste.app_factory = foo.app:make_app
```

And in your code:

```
def make_app(global_conf, **local_conf):
     return application
```

Comment: Hi gawel,as I didn' want to add PasteMonster to my wsgi stack, I mad my own mini recipe using z3c.recipe.runscript (damn useful when you need extreme stuffs that are not supported by known recipes).

Comment: If it can help someone else, here's what in the buildout.cfg file.

<!-- language: lang-none -->

    [wsgiscript]

    # Construction du script pour Apache / mod_wsgi
    recipe = z3c.recipe.runscript
    install-script = ${buildout:directory}/buildouthelpers.py:make_wsgi_script
    update-script = ${:install-script}

    # Paramètres pour le script
    egg = loix.xqueryproxy
    script = ${buildout:parts-directory}/wsgiscript/xqueryproxy.wsgi
    app = loix.xqueryproxy.app.app

Comment: I created a recipe based on `collective.recipe.modwsgi` that does not require Paste - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mk.recipe.modwsgi